# Long running background task is not working properly in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I have a long-running background task to find similar images in a device. I have implemented code with operation queue and assign it QoS to background. Sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes it does not.

```
photoScanningOperationQueue.name = "photo_scanning"
photoScanningOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
photoScanningOperationQueue.qualityOfService = .background
photoScanningOperationQueue.underlyingQueue = .global(qos: .background)
```

In the simulator it does not suspend the app completely, it just stops the process and gives this error but in the real device, it just stops the app and when launch from start when loaded from background.

`assertion's invalidation time is in the past`

I have used code below to achieve long-running background task

```
extension DuplicatePhotoFinderVC {
    func setupBackgrounding() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBackgrounding(_:)), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appForegrounding(_:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func appBackgrounding(_ notification: Notification?) {
        keepAlive()
    }

    @objc func keepAlive() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
            self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
            if self.photoScanningOperationQueue.operationCount > 0 {
                self.keepAlive()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In the viewDidLoad method, I have called setupBackgrounding(). 
I'm not sure what is causing this issue. I have tried to debug for 2 days and I can't find a root cause or solution to my problem.
If you can spot a problem and give solution it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: Note the `background` QoS is nothing to do with background execution of your app.  It is just the lowest priority.  You would typically avoid this QoS as it can be starved; For example, queues with this QoS are not dispatched when the device is in low power mode.  Prior to iOS 13 you can only execute in the background for 3 minutes.  On iOS 13 you should look at [`BGTaskScheduler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler) - It gives you more control over discretionary background tasks including executing only when connected to power.

Comment: When you get a call to the expiration handler it means that your background time is up.  You can't just start another background task.  Once your background time is used you can only start a new background task after the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: Can you give me an example of BGTaskScheduler? Do you have any other option to run a task in the background because in iOS 12 this issue is there?

Comment: This [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/) covers `BGTaskScheduler`.  Prior to iOS 13 you can use background refresh.